# .NET Winforms: prevent button click trigger for a multiline textbox on a "AcceptButton" enabled form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog

Well my problem is this: I set the AcceptButton on a form and this gives me the nice effect that it triggers the buttons Click event, but if I'm on a MultiLine textbox I don't want this to happen. Then I just want it to put a enter in it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set "AcceptsReturn" property of the textbox to true.

Answer (score 6):

There is a property on the `TextBox` control:

```
textbox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
```

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn(v=vs.110).aspx)